# Smaller speedup than expected by precomputing encoded output in full pairwise comparison

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, tf.keras, siamese-network

I am building a neural net to predict the outcome of pairwise comparison. The same encoder network is applied on both inputs before merging and computing the result in the downstream part. In my use case, I am computing all the pairwise predictions for a given set of elements, as such the number of predictions grows very quickly, thus I am interested in speeding-up the prediction process.

Doing the complete set of pairwise predictions naively involves computing the result of the encoder network on each of the element over and over again. Since the encoder network is bigger than the downstream part (merging + layers downstream), I thought that precomputing the result of the encoder network on each input element and then only computing the downstream on these encoded values would lead to significant speed-up. However that is not really what I find in practice. For the example below both on Colab (CPU) and on my machine (CPU), I can get savings of 10-15% of runtimes when I would have expected something like 50% if you think in terms of layers and even more if you think in terms of parameters.

I feel like I am missing something, either in the implementation or that tensorflow/keras already does some kind of magic (caching?) given the structure of the network thus leading to smaller gains?

```py
import numpy as np # numpy will be used for mgrid to compute all the pairs of the input
import tensorflow as tf

# Encoder Network
input_a = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,4))
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input_a)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)
upstream_network = tf.keras.Model(input_a, x)

# Downstream network, from merge to final prediction
input_downstream_a = tf.keras.Input(shape = upstream_network.layers[-1].output_shape[1:])
input_downstream_b = tf.keras.Input(shape = upstream_network.layers[-1].output_shape[1:])
x = tf.keras.layers.subtract([input_downstream_a, input_downstream_b])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
downstream_network = tf.keras.Model((input_downstream_a, input_downstream_b), x)

# Full network
input_full_a = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,4))
input_full_b = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,4))
intermed_a = upstream_network(input_full_a)
intermed_b = upstream_network(input_full_b)
res = downstream_network([intermed_a, intermed_b])
full_network = tf.keras.Model([input_full_a, input_full_b], res)
full_network.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Experiment
population = np.random.random((300, 10, 4))

# %%timeit 10 
# 1.9s on Colab CPU
indices = np.mgrid[range(population.shape[0]), range(population.shape[0])].reshape(2, -1)
full_network.predict([population[indices[0]], population[indices[1]]])

# %%timeit 10
# 1.7s on Colab CPU 
out = upstream_network.predict(population)
indices = np.mgrid[range(population.shape[0]), range(population.shape[0])].reshape(2, -1)
downstream_network.predict([out[indices[0]], out[indices[1]]])
```

Comment: you are not be able to test it using small input population, you may try bigger input size 600, 700, 800

Comment: The population is not that small because of the np.mgrid (which does the product), it corresponds to 90,000 samples in the case of a population of 300

Comment: Hmm, but increasing population significantly could be more informative even 90,000 ,it's vary based on the complexity of each function you may need more than 90,000 to have a good comparison and you may not, but in your case there's no significant change about 1 second at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are not going to be able to test time, using **small input** population, you may try bigger input size **600**, **700**, **800**, but even though, the prediction time not going to increase a lot.

In your case I suggest using `predict_on_batch` **rather than** `predict`, as it's not going to split your input to n batches, which a time consuming task, and `predict_on_batch` is more reasonable in case of your data could be fitted into **google colab memory**

`full_network.predict_on_batch([population[indices[0]], population[indices[1]]])`

Using your test case `(300, 10, 4)` - `predict_on_batch`

---

```
array([[0.5       ],
       [0.5022318 ],
       [0.47754446],
       ...,
       [0.50507313],
       [0.4884554 ],
       [0.5       ]], dtype=float32)

time: 216 ms
```

Comment: For population size 1,000 (so 1e6 pairs to predict), the difference is even more staggering. 17.9s (predict) vs 154ms (predict_on_batch), both on Collab CPU (`%%timeit 10`). Thanks a lot @m-zayan